# Merging channels results in artificats in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm seperating an RGB picture and then I do thresholding on each channels, then when I merge the 3 channels I get artificats like in the following picture.
[image]

```
 b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
    r = cv2.threshold(r, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    g = cv2.threshold(g, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    b = cv2.threshold(b, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    rgb_image = cv2.merge([b, g, r])

    k = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 15))
    blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(rgb_image, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, k)

    mask = cv2.inRange(rgb_image, (225, 225, 225), (255, 255, 255))

    # dst = np.dstack((frame, 255-mask))
    dst = np.dstack((rgb_image, mask))


    cv2.imshow('lo', dst)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: what is the expected result by merging the thresholded images?

Comment: an image without the artifiacts that's there, I need just the black text